# MySql 8.0.20 server fail to install on windows

Tags: mysql, installation

Hello I've tried to install mysql server on my Desktop to implement an app but the installer can't install the mysql server. I read all about the microsoft c++ redistributable problems but at me it isn't problem because in logs dosen't say nothing about that error(It says if any vcredist is missing). Anyway I installed all the versions from vcredist what the mysql needed but after all it just stop when install and don't get information what else should failing. All the others plugins and features is installed just this one keep failing. Anybody met with this problem before?  [image]

Comment: This might be a known bug please check this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92392.

Comment: Happy to help!!